# Reducing page load time while using Document AI API

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I used **v1 API** as mentioned in the below link in **Laravel 8 web app** using **curl** but the page load time is increasing.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#documentai_process_document-drest

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
-d @request.json \
https://LOCATION-documentai.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/processors/PROCESSOR_ID:process
```

What to do to reduce page load time ?

Comment: What do you mean by time is increasing? Each time you execute curl page is loading longer? This snippet is working as expected but it takes longer each time? You are executing it from GCP console?

Comment: I mean the page load is increasing but that is expected as it's a curl hit.

I am making curl call in a Laravel Controller. Is it possible to reduce the page load time ?

Comment: What do you have inside `request.json`? You are running it on GCP on your local machine? Could you provide some overview?